# Persistant storage for 100+ items in a shopping cart

Tags: mysql, asp-classic, shopping-cart, session-storage

Can I use a MySQL database session storage table to save and restore a shopping cart with over 100 products in it on a site that was built with Classic ASP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend:
In your database table, create a field to uniquely identify the user. Perhaps a string type for email address? Or if you are going further, "ID_user".
This will allow your user to call up their "wishlist" or "saved cart" when they come back to the site. See tables in image below called users, cart, cart_details, wishlist, etc.

Here is a snapshot of a database I designed for a CMS that has a shopping cart and wishlist. Hope it helps!
[image]

Comment: Maybe the question is not clear enough. I run a trade only website and and one of my trade customers adds 110 products to their shopping basket (which does happen occasionally), and then gets called away in their retail business to attend to whatever. The cart data is too large for a session cookie to retain so can I use a db session storage table to restore all the products into the cart after their session expires?

Comment: See the edit I made to my answer above. Oh and yeah, you can use a cookie but only use it to store a unique ID for your cart or wishlist table. I would usually store either ID_user or ID_session in that cookie.